# Isolate all variables to LHS in sympy?

Tags: python, sympy

I am using sympy to process some equations. I want to write the equations in a canonical form such that variables of interest are all on LHS. For eg. if I have,

```
lhs = sympify("e*x +f")`
rhs = sympify("g*y + t*x +h")`
eq = Eq(lhs,rhs)
e*x + f == g*y + h + t*x
```

I need a function which can isolate a list of given variables (my so called canonical form), like

```
IsolateVariablesToLHS(eq,[x,y]) # desired function
(e-t)*x - g*y == h-f # now x and y are on LHS and remaining are on RHS
```

I have the assurance that I will only get linear equations, so this is always possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
>>> import sympy as sm
>>> lhs = sm.sympify('e*x + f')
>>> rhs = sm.sympify('g*y + t*x + h')
>>> eq = sm.Eq(lhs, rhs)
```

Here's a simple construct

```
def isolateVariablesToLHS(eq, syms):
    l = sm.S.Zero
    eq = eq.args[0] - eq.args[1]
    for e in syms:
        ind = eq.as_independent(e)[1]
        l += ind
        eq -= ind
    return sm.Eq(l, eq)

>>> isolateVariablesToLHS(eq, [x, y])
Eq(e*x - g*y - t*x, f - h)
```

Answer (score 0):

With the equation as provided in the question combine all the terms and construct a filter for discovering the required variables.

```
>>> from itertools import filterfalse
>>> terms = eq.lhs - eq.rhs
>>> vars = ['x', 'y']
>>> filt = lambda t: any(t.has(v) for v in vars)
>>> result = Eq(sum(filter(filt, terms.args)), - sum(filterfalse(filt, terms.args))
>>> result
e*x - g*y - t*x == -f + h
```

I'm not familiar with sympy but I think this will work for equations consisting of proper atoms such as Symbols. Make sure you replace the vars list with the actual instantiated Symbols x, y instead of the 'ascii' representations. This is probably required to combine terms that have variables in common.

filter and filterfalse might have different names in python 2.x, but this functionality is probably still in the itertools package.